# Как получить значения между часами?

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, sqlite3

Есть задача, получить данные между 2 часами (например между 11 и 14) и сделать из них график, пробовал `range`, но всегда одно из значений пропадает:

```
x = []
y = []
xFrom = 11
xTo = 14
for hour in range(int(xFrom), int(xTo)):
    x.append(hour)
    cursor.execute("SELECT count FROM users WHERE hour = ?;", (hour,))
    records = cursor.fetchall()
    print(records)
    for record in records:
        y.append(record[0])
        break
x.append(xTo)
print(x)
print(y)
ax = plt.gca()
ax.set_facecolor("white")
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.savefig(str(call.message.chat.id) + '.png')
bot.send_photo(call.message.chat.id, open(str(call.message.chat.id) + '.png', 'rb'))
os.remove(str(call.message.chat.id) + '.png')
```

И вывод получается такой (тут я пробовал между 9 и 12 часами):

```
[(2901,)]
[(3012,)]
[(2581,)]
[9, 10, 11, 12]
[2901, 3012, 2581]
```

И из-за этого matplotlib не может правильно построить график.

Вот база данных:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Гораздо проще сразу выбрать все нужные вам записи одним запросом и избавиться от ненужного цикла:

```
cursor.execute(
    "SELECT hour, count FROM users WHERE hour between ? and ?", 
    (xFrom, xTo)
)
```

PS не стоит называть столбцы в таблицах зарезервированными именами (`count`). В SQL существует функция `count()` для подсчета количества строк.

Answer (score 2):

Кажется, вы просто не понимаете, как работает `range` в питоне. Он **не включает** правую границу при переборе. Вы потом "вручную" добавляете в `x` правую границу уже после цикла через `x.append(xTo)`, но значение то по этому `x` вы в базе не запрашиваете в цикле и не получаете. Вам нужно поправить аргументы `range`, если я всё правильно понял. И `int` там лишние, у вас уже целые числа же там:

```
for hour in range(xFrom, xTo + 1):
                            ^^^^
```

А ручное добавление правой границы в `x` уберите:

```
x.append(xTo) # <- это не нужно
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное!